# Is it possible to consume environment variables inside of npm / package.json?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, package.json

I'm attempting to build a package.json so that when running a NodeJS app on Heroku it will run the scripts.postinstall step using an environment variable. For example:

```
...
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "command $ENV_VAR"}
},
...
```

I've looked at the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and wasn't able to find something saying I can.

Is this even possible? Is this even desirable and "I'm Doing It Wrong"™?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer due to new packages having been written**

You can use the [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) package to do this in a clean way:

```
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "postinstall": "cross-var command $ENV_VAR",
  ...
},
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "cross-var": "^1.1.0",
  ...
}
...
```

**Original answer**

To answer the last questions, because they're the most important one: yes, no, and absolutely, because you've just broken cross-platform compatibility. There is no guarantee your environment syntax works for all shells on all operating systems, so don't do this.

We have a guaranteed cross-platform technology available to us already: Node. So, create a file called something like `bootstrap.js`, and then make npm run `node bootstrap` as your postinstall script. Since the code inside `bootstrap.js` will run like any other node script, it'll have access to `process.env` in a fully cross-platform compatible way, and everyone will be happy.

And many, many, *many* things that use common utils have node equivalents, so you can `npm` install them, locally rather than globally, and then call them in an npm script. For instance `mkdir -p` is not cross-platform, but installing the `mkdirp` module is, and then an npm script like `"ensuredirs": "mkdirp dist/assets"` works fine *everywhere* when run as `npm run ensuredirs`

And for convenience, the most common unix utilities have their own runner package, [shx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx), which is fully cross-platform and makes the lives of devs even easier, with the "if you're writing code" equivalent being [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shx).

Answer (score 14):

Ignore the nay-sayers.  You can do this in a cross-platform manner using [`cross-var`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var):

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cross-var command $ENV_VAR"
}
```

Comment: (but note that cross-var didn't exist when this question was posted)