# NPM persist environment variable across scripts

Tags: node.js, npm

I'd like to set an environment variable or npm config right before `npm install` is run.

Setting it in `preinstall` doesn't persist it. Neither does calling `npm config set ...` in `preinstall`.

Comment: Could it be set in your .bashrc? That way each time the shell loads, you load those env vars.

Comment: Alternatively, use a `.env` file and read from that using [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package?

Comment: You could use a shell script that sets the environment variable(s) and then calls `npm install`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't set that variable ahead of time. It's specific to the environment the package is being installed on. And I don't have access to change how/when ` npm install` is run. (otherwise I could just do `VAR=blah npm install`)

Comment: Does this answer help? [32980057](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980057/is-it-possible-to-consume-environment-variables-inside-of-npm-package-json)

Comment: @RichS, it does not. But thanks

Comment: Also linking: [51162609](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51162609/why-cant-i-set-env-variables-by-running-a-bash-script-from-an-npm-script?rq=1).

Comment: So, to generalize this... if there's an npm script,`"set_env_var": "export MYVAR=321 && echo $MYVAR"`, running `npm run set_env_var` will echo 123, but back in the bash shell, echo $MYVAR won't show anything. However, something like this would persist the var: `"set_env_var": "MYVAR=321 && echo $MYVAR > .env"`. Then consume that .env file. That .env file is your persistence.